# Using a Nelify function for Mailjet subscriptions

Tags: javascript, netlify, mailjet, netlify-function, mailerlite

I'm trying to set up a newsletter subscription form on a site hosted on Netlify. When a user submits an email address, I'd like it to be added to my contact list on Mailjet. To do this without a third-party service like Zapier, it's necessary to use a Netlify function with environment variables.

I have searched and tried everything but just can't get this to work.

[Here is a promising tutorial](https://duncanteege.com/blog/how-to-create-an-email-subscription-form-in-nextjs-netlify-and-mailerlite) for MailerLite, which I'm willing to try, but I couldn't get this to work either. [Here is another](https://andrewstiefel.com/netlify-functions-email-subscription/) for some different email services, and [here is yet another tutorial](https://css-tricks.com/using-netlify-forms-and-netlify-functions-to-build-an-email-sign-up-widget/) for doing so with Buttondown.

I don't know javascript well enough to adapt these to Mailjet or MailerLite.

Can anyone please provide functional code that can simply be copy-pasted into my `/functions/subscribeToMailjet.js` or `/functions/subscribeToMailerLite.js` file?

Comment: This is answered here:

https://answers.netlify.com/t/netlify-function-to-add-contact-to-mailjet/100326